# The Console application has exited with code 0 (0x0) although unhandled exception occured

Tags: c#

I'm writing very simple code of .Net Framework (4.7) Console Application and intentionally throw unhanded exception. But still the program exit with code 0 (0x0), which supposed to indicate successful accomplishment.

According to Microsoft documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.exitcode?view=netframework-4.8) 
The default value is 0 (zero), which indicates that the process completed successfully.

My Q is: I`m expecting any exit code but no 0. Can someone explain me what I'm missing here?

My code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {                    
            throw new Exception("Throw an exception");

            Console.WriteLine("Finishing program");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

The output window (Debug) message:

*An unhandled exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in ConsoleApp2.exe*

*Throw an exception*

*The program '[7480] ConsoleApp2.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).*

Thanks a lot

Comment: You don’t set any exit code - neither via `Environment.ExitCode nor via `static int Main(…) { return <your-exit-code>; }` - thus the default exit code applies. How, would the framework know what the correct error exit code for each specific exception should be?

Comment: First, I vaguely remember that only console apps can have meaningful exit codes. Window apps have no need for such functionality. Second, maybe you have to set the exit code yourself. Catch the exception, and set the exit code there.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        bool continueThrow = true;
        static int Main(string[] args)
        {   
             try{
                 //doThings
             }catch(Exception ex){
                 //log the exception;
                 Environment.ExitCode = number;
                 if(continueThrow){
                      throw;
                 }
            } 
            Console.WriteLine("Finishing program");
            Console.ReadLine();

            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is just plain wrong. The exit code will not be zero if an unhandled exception was thrown. The OPs problem comes from the bug stated by Mike Nakis

Comment: See [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). Your answer could do with an explanation.

Answer (score 9):

This is happening due to... (tadaaa...)

### A bug in the visual studio debugger!

The debugger reports that the exit code is zero, but ***the debugger is lying to you*** and the exit code is in fact non-zero.

The bug is discussed here: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/35599#issuecomment-621954472

I quote:

> The Visual Studio debugger has a quirk that it reports exit code of programs that terminated due to unhandled exceptions as 0 on Windows, but that only happens when you run the program from VS debugger. It does not happen when you run the program from the command line.

(Note how they are calling it a *quirk* instead of a bug; the hubris of this company is mind-boggling.)

Try running your program from a batch file and display `%errorlevel%` to see the real exit code.

### Wait, it gets better!

If you use a batch file to see the exit code, you might be surprised to discover that it is still not the value you chose; instead, it is -532462766.

That's right, the exit code is -532462766.

Not 0, not 42, not -532462765, but exactly -532462766.

WTF, right?

In 32-bit hex, this number is 0xE0434352, which is a nameless, largely undocumented, blanket HRESULT that basically stands for "error due to some application-specific reasons, we are not telling you exactly what." In this case, the application-specific reason is that an unhandled DotNet exception caused the process to crash. Rumor has it that this HRESULT is known as "EXCEPTION_COMPLUS" or "CLR_EXCEPTION_V4", although good luck finding a shred of documentation for that. Also, I could claim that the last 6 hex digits, 434352, spell "CCR", which is a reference to a well known rock band of the 1970ies, good luck refuting my claim!

### Wait, it gets even better!

At this point you might be tempted to try various ways of coercing windows to report an exit code of your own choice instead of the nonsensical -532462766 exit code. You might try:

- catching the exception and setting `ExitCode` before rethrowing it;
- catching the exception and invoking `Environment.Exit()` passing your own exit code;
- registering an AppDomain unhandled exception handler and setting `ExitCode` in there;
- registering an AppDomain unhandled exception handler and invoking `Environment.Exit()` with your own exit code from within the handler;

etc.

It will all be a waste of time. None of it will work. Microsoft has gone to great lengths to make sure that in the event of an unhandled exception, a DotNet process will terminate with exit code -532462766 and nothing but exit code -532462766.

> -532462766 should be enough for everyone.

Resistance is futile. You will be assimilated.